# My 4 month old Cockateil makes some odd noises as if it is talking with someone else. Do I need to worry about such behaviour?

Tags: birds, vocalizations, cockatiels

My Cockatiel which is around 3-4 months old, seems to make noises that resemble "Talking". These noises are often made when it is in a free mood but not in any other uncomfortable situations.
I'm worried if it is trying to convey some kind of message that I couldn't understand.

I have two cockatiels. One is very active- (easy going, playful) and the other one is very calm going, (but often attacks with beak when I try to take it into hands) and only active when it needs to have fun. The cockatiel which is not always active/playful has this "Talking" behavior. I have noticed this behavior since not more than a month.
The other cockatiel doesn't bother/respond to these sounds.

Comment: Take a video of this behavior if you can, though I think I know what you're describing, my cockatiel does this too.